# How do i add velocity to a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I add velocity to a player? I know how to spawn mobs with velocity I suppose that would be the same?

Comment: It's not the same. A player's entity data can not be changed directly.

Answer (score 2):

A player's data cannot be changed without modifications to the game. Player data is handled differently to entitydata, so /entitydata can't change the velocity of a player. However, you can use /execute and /summon to create creepers or primed TNT without a fuse (causing them to explode immediately) in order to blast players around. This is very unreliable though. Another alternative could be to use constant /tp commands to make the player move in a certain direction constantly, however it can take a lot of tweaking to get it to work and it might be slightly choppy.